# Preventing Concurrent Updates in Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a route/view in my Flask application where I am editing an existing record and I want to ensure that my changes are only committed to the database if I am updating the latest version of the record.

For example, my application has a Vegetable object, which has a field called name. The "Edit Vegetable" route/view is based on a form in which the name field is first populated with the existing value for the Vegetable.

Scenario 1: User A opens the "Edit Vegetable" page for a specific record. The name field is populated with the existing name of "Courgete". As this is not spelt correctly, the User is going to change it to "Courgette". However, they get distracted and don't press the Save button for a few minutes. In between them editing the name and pressing the Save button, User B, their colleague from the USA, opens the page for same record, changes the name to "Zucchini" and saves it. I would like User A to get a warning or even prevent them updating the record when they press the Save button as they are effectively no longer editing the latest version of the record.

Scenario 2: User A goes back through their browser history until they get to the previous Edit Vegetable record where they originally changed the name of the Vegetable to "Courgete". Again, I would like a warning or to prevent User A pressing the Save button and updating the record, as again, they are not updating the latest version of the record.

I am newbie, and in all of the tutorials that I have looked at, these considerations are not mentioned and I have not been able to find a solution through a web search, though that might be because I am not searching with the right terms. I tried having an updated datetime on Vegetable object that gets updated when the record is updated. However, I couldn't work out how to then check this as before it seems that before it does the update, the POST reloads the Vegetable object. Below is a simplified version of my code. I am using Flask-WTF and sqlalchemy.

```
@app.route("/edit_vegetable/<int:id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit_vegetable(id):
    vegetable = Vegetable.query.get(id)
    form = VegetableForm()
    if request.method == "GET":
        form.name.data = vegetable.name
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
        vegetable.name = request.form.get("name")
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("vegetable_list"))
    return render_template("edit_vegetable.html", form=form)
```

As I stated earlier, I am a newbie. I am currently learning Flask and I haven't yet got as far as JavaScript, so if a solution involves JavaScript I am not likely to understand it (yet).

Comment: You can use SQLAlchemy's [`with_for_update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=update#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_for_update) which will lock the row/columns pending so only 1 user can edit at a time.

Comment: @noslenkwah - Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it. However, at first glance it would seem to mean that in Scenario 1, User B would not be able to update the record until User A saves their changes. Potentially, a record could be locked for a long period of time, which might be problematic and require some means of freeing the lock. I cannot immediately see how "with for update" would help in scenario 2.

Comment: When you go through your browsers history, it's still going to reload whatever url the user requested. The page will still be updated with the most current object. Regardless, you can use a hidden checksum field to validate which version of the object you are editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I managed to implement this by doing the following:

My record has an updated DateTime field (vegetable.updated) on it, so I added it a Hidden field to my form:

```
hidden_updated_datetime = HiddenField()
```

which I then added to my jinja template.

In my view/route, I added a check to see if the value in this hidden field is different to the updated field on the vegetable object retrieved by the POST. This then re-renders the edit_vegetable.html rather than proceeding with the update:

```
if form.hidden_updated_datetime.data != str(vegetable.updated):
    flash("Update failed - not updating the latest version", "danger")
    return render_template("edit_vegetable.html", form=form)
```

Note that the vegetable.updated field is being converted to a string as WTForm Hidden fields are string fields.

Potentially, rather than getting the vegetable object again, I realise that I could also add the id as hidden field in the same manner as the updated datetime field, and then try to execute an update statement with a where clause based on the id and the updated dateime from the hidden form fields. If zero rows are returned by the update, I would know that the record has been changed in the meantime.